# How to fix Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method when apply multiple filters to a table based off cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2016. I have two sheets in my workbook. I would like to apply two filters to a table on Sheet2 using values from 2 different cells entered on Sheet1. I'm very new to VBA and I think the issue lies with my filtering, but I'm not sure.

I've tried a few variations of this ListObject code, but all ended in the same error message and this was the cleanest version.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFilter_Table()
'''Filters analysis table to the selected vendor(s)/brand(s) combinations entered on the Information & MACROS tab

Dim vendor As Range, brand As Range
With Sheets("Information_and_MACROS")
    Set vendor = .Range("E19")
    Set brand = .Range("E22")
End With
'''selects vendors/brands to use in filter

Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Worksheets("qry_cost_change_analysis").ListObjects("cost_change_analysis")

With Sheets("qry_cost_change_analysis")
    With .lo
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vendor
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=brand
    End With
End With
'''applies filter to the table


End Sub
```

I tested this by enter a value in both fields and expected the data table to be filtered to only show the applicable data. However, I only received the run time error.

Comment: `with lo.autofilter.range` since the `autofilter` **method** belongs to the `Range` object.

Answer (score 0):

Error 438 means a late-bound member call failed to resolve.

```
With Sheets("qry_cost_change_analysis")
```

Since `Sheets` returns an `Object`, any member call chained to it is late-bound. Avoid this. Extract local variables, and type them explicitly:

```
Dim costChangeAnalysisSheet As Worksheet
Set costChangeAnalysisSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("qry_cost_change_analysis")

With costChangeAnalysisSheet
    .lo '<~ won't show up on intellisense, illegal: "lo" isn't a member of "Worksheet"
```

You probably meant to work `With lo`, [as Rory suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874703/how-to-fix-run-time-error-438-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-w#comment98409323_55874703).